# Angular Material dialog doesnt shrink

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material, angular-material2

[image]

[image]

have many dialog boxes and i been playing with height 100% and layouts , its just not goign away, the space after the button is not auto shrinking like a regular mdDialog. I can play with break line and layout padding to make it look ok when the map is on since its only little bit of space. But when the map is turned off like the second pic, the space is tool large. How do i solve this preferably an angular material solution

```html
<md-dialog class="updateLocationMap" flex="50" >
  <form name="updateLocationForm">

    <md-toolbar>
      <close-dialog label="{{'MENU-ITEMS.UPDATELOC-PARENT' | translate}}"></close-dialog>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-dialog-content >
      <div layout layout-padding>
        
        <si-parent-search
          on-update="ctrl.updateSelectedParent(selected)"
          classification='ctrl.asset.classification'
          pre-select='ctrl.asset.parents[ctrl.asset.parents.length -1]'
        ></si-parent-search>
        
        <span flex></span>
        
        <md-switch ng-model='ctrl.useMap'>Use Map</md-switch>
      </div>
      
<div layout-padding>
      <si-coordinate-select ng-if='ctrl.useMap'
        on-update='ctrl.updateLatLong(lat, long)'
        mapid='update-location-xs'
      ></si-coordinate-select>
</div>
      <div ng-if='!ctrl.useMap' layout layout-xs='column' layout-padding>
          <md-input-container flex class="md-accent">
              <label translate="LABELS.LAT"></label>
              <input ng-model="ctrl.asset.latitude"  required>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container flex class="md-accent">
              <label translate="LABELS.LONG"></label>
              <input ng-model="ctrl.asset.longitude" required>
          </md-input-container>
      </div>

    </md-dialog-content>
    
    <md-dialog-actions layout-padding >
      <md-button aria-label="Close Dialog" ng-click="ctrl.cancel()" class="md-accent" translate="BUTTON.CANCEL"></md-button>
      <input ng-if="!ctrl.useMap" type="submit"  ng-click="ctrl.submit()" value="{{'BUTTON.UPDATE' | translate}}" class="md-button md-accent">
      <input ng-if="ctrl.useMap" type="submit" ng-disabled="updateLocationForm.$invalid" ng-click="ctrl.submit()" value="{{'BUTTON.UPDATE' | translate}}" class="md-button md-accent">
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: Better to post working code through a plunker/fiddle

Comment: i've seen this before. You must play around a bit with the content flex and layout. I think you must define it as flex in order for it to get the available space and have the buttons at the bottom at all times. For further info please provide a demo

Answer (score 1):

solved the issue by using height:auto inside

removed the layout padding from the md-dialog-actions this solved the issue